# Separate parts of the mesh will not stay with the rig

Tags: mesh, rigging, armature

I have a character that I am currently trying to rig, and he has an object attacked to his shoulder. The problem is, I cannot for the life of me, get the object to stay above his shoulder while he raises his arm. It goes from this:
[image: Start]

To this:
[image: End]

I've tried making seperate bones for it, re-rigging, re-assigning vertex groups, and a bit of weight painting (not very experienced with it).

This question may be a duplicate, but none of the other questions here seem to work when I try it. Thanks!

Comment: Since I can't add more than two links, here is my blend file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/m71ru124gmpe3w4/LowLevelMedievalWarrior.blend?dl=0

Comment: It's working fine for me. Maybe try restarting your Blender or your computer?

Comment: Well, if worked, for some reason. I remember restarting blender many times yesterday, but it did nothing. Maybe it was the computer restart that solved it. Anyways, thanks! I would've never though restarting my whole computer would solve it.

Comment: Glad to help out!